# How to move specified Key+Values into another Dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, key

Let's suppose I have a dictionary, a list, and an empty dictionary

```
x = {1: {550: 54, 1: 30, 2: 39}, 2: {80: 2}, 3: {9: 10, 8: 11}}

y = [1, 2]

z = {}
```

Since 1 is in x I want to append key 1 and its values to z. Same with key 2 and its values. How about would I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```py
z = {k:x[k] for k in y}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like so:

```
for key in y:
    z[key] = x[key]
```

or, if you are so inclined:

```
z = {key: x[key] for key in y}
```